# Why choose Solana exchange instead of others?

Tags: solana-program, account, transfer

I just log into this exchange and I need to understand why use this exchange

Comment: `stackexchange.com` is a platform for questions and answers about all sorts of topics. `solana.stackexchange.com` is the section of this website dedicated to questions and answers about the Solana blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! In stackexchange, new exchanges are proposed over in Area51: https://area51.stackexchange.com

As you can see, the Solana proposal has been a quite successful one. If you're curious I'd advise you to try and investigate the rationale behind this proposal. I will avoid making my own personal statements about this decision.

Searching "Solana" in https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com lead me to some posts which might be of your interest: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=solana

Now, in a more practical sense, it might make sense to post your question both here and in the Stackoverflow. There's no rule against that. I have a preference for posting here as, in my mind, it feels both less cluttered and that I'm contributing to its growth.